# CSS Image Doesn't Cover Screen

Tags: php, image, resize

I have a website where I have an image that I would like to cover my entire screen width wise.

Here is my css:

```
            .header {
            background-image:url('images/header.png');
            height: 120px;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            z-index:1;          
        }
```

My bug is that, if I resize the browser window so it has a scroll bar and I scroll to the right my image stops drawing after a certain point.  It seems that the image is drawing 100% width of window but it doesn't apply if some of the window is not visible, and only is via using the scroll bar.

How do I fix this?  Here is a picture of my problem:

Edge of screen before scrolling right:

[image]

Edge of screen after scrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:cover;` and `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

```
.header {
        background-image:url('images/header.png');
        background-size:cover;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height: 120px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        z-index:1;          
    }
```

Currently, you are not telling the background image to 'stretch' so it stays fixed in it's original dimensions.

You also have ANOTHER problem - your html css property is not set to width:100%; your bootstrap.css is overriding it.
Therefore, your header element stretches to 100% of html element, which is not 100% of the screen's width.

Find your local css and add (or edit) the current html & body rules:

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Make sure it is loaded AFTER the bootstrap css (and therefore overrides bootstrap.css).

If it still makes problems, try using

`width:100% !important;`

Just for general knowledge, I recommend using your browsers' built in inspector tool (or FireBug) to see the element on the screen and what's their dynamic css values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm, I put in your code but I still have the same bug..  http://i.imgur.com/2UcRjBG.png

Comment: @user3130731 can you set up a JSFiddle or send a link to your site?

Comment: www.rune-shadows.com is my site.  To re-create the bug, resize your screen if there is no bottom scroll bar and then move right and the top image will cut off.

Comment: @user3130731 I was able to reproduce the error. It's not a bug, take a look at my revised answer.

Comment: I changed my body {} to this,                                     body {
 background-image: url('images/background.png');
 width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}                                                                     It doesn't work and I'm confused as to what to do, I also did the width:100% !important;

Comment: you need to change html rules not body. I just added the body rules to make sure but your html rules are blocking you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46284/discussion-between-user3130731-and-yani)